# How can I access an online JSON file from offline? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am making a weather website for my school project using the [Wunderground Weather API](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/). This is the code I am using to get the JSON data:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.wunderground.com/api/<apikey>/conditions/q/" + wlocation + ".json", function(data){
    alert(data);
});
```

The `<apikey>` is where I put my API key, and the `$` character is just a shortcut for JQuery.

When I open this webpage, which is local, not published, no alert pops up and I get the error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.wunderground.com/api/<apikey>/conditions/q/<myzipcode>.json. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

After doing some research on this error, it sounds like I might have to create a web server. However, for the project, we need to turn it in as a folder of .html and other "web files". Is there another way to do this or do I have to make a web server? This project is due soon, so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a code sample from the link that you provided in your original post (http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=resources/code-samples). they use JSONP. yes, as @antyrat said, it is a CORS problem.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $.ajax({
      url : "http://api.wunderground.com/api/Your_Key/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/Cedar_Rapids.json",
      dataType : "jsonp",
      success : function(parsed_json) {
          var location = parsed_json['location']['city'];
          var temp_f = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f'];
          alert("Current temperature in " + location + " is: " + temp_f);
      }
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) for this.

I'm not sure if *Wunderground Weather API* have some kind of callbacks in JSON. But if they do even jQuery `getJSON` support JSONP.

Seems like you run into [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: @Nikola Umm... Have you read wiki article I've provided? There is all code you need. I don't think there is something like tutorial because JSONP is just JSON with callback function, that's it!

Comment: Since you are using jQuery - help with this.  From the [.getJSON docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) "JSONP

If the URL includes the string "callback=?" (or similar, as defined by the server-side API), the request is treated as JSONP instead. See the discussion of the jsonp data type in $.ajax() for more details."

Comment: @antyrat Now I feel silly. However, I did find a little tutorial at http://www.w3resource.com/JSON/JSONP.php